# Unity, get random position within an area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, spawning

as the image below shows, I would like to find a random position within the blue area (B) and not the red area (A). How can I achieve this? A and B are currently 2 colliders. I just need a position within B but it cant be within A. Thanks in advance.

[A and B areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq6CI.png)

Comment: Find a position in B and if it is also in A, try again (i.e. rejection sampling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Solution is same as  Nico Schertler has mentioned in the comment

1. Get the coordinate of each vertices of both the rectangle.
2. take the x coordinate of min x of blue triangle and min coordinate of red triangle as a pair.(xminBlue,xminRed). Take the x coordinate of max x of red triangle and max coordinate of blue triangle as a pair.(xmaxRed,xmaxBlue)
3. Do the same for Y coordinate and get (yminBlue,yminRed) .  (ymaxRed,ymaxBlue)
4. Use
   `if(Random.value < GetRatio(xminBlue-xminRed),xmaxRed-xmaxBlue){
           x= Random.Range(xminBlue,xminRed);
       }else
       {
           x= Random.Range(xmaxRed,xmaxBlue);
       }
   float GetRatio (float distance_1,float distance_2){
       return distance_1 / distance_1 + distance_2;

   }`
   [image]
5. Do the same as 4 to get the value of y

In this solution u dont need to reject any coordinate

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, its just what I needed and very straightforward to understand.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine, just one question, why the < 0.5f?

Comment: sorry do not use random.value < 0.5f instead use the above code i have edited .this will help you to get value with equal probability any were in the blue region

Comment: and for the y axis, the if statement should be like if (Rand

Comment: and for the y axis, the if statement should be like if (Random.value < GetRatio(yMinRed - yMinBlue, yMaxBlue - yMaxRed))?